# How to drag and rotate svg elements?

Tags: html, svg, rotation, move, drag

So far i've made a user interface which allows you to select a number, and then it creates that amount of svg squares.

I need to be able to make each svg square rotatable and movable. Similar to the way you rotate and drag around images on microsoft office.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var number = 0;
    var squares = 0;
var h = ""
var x = '<svg width="100" height="100"><rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg>';

    function button1() {
        number = 1;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }

    function button2() {
        number = 2;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }

    function button3() {
        number = 3
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }

    function button4() {
        number = 4;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }

    function button5() {
        number = 5;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }

    function button6() {
        number = 6;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }

    function button7() {
        number = 7;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }

    function button8() {
        number = 8;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }

    function button9() {
        number = 9;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }

    function button10() {
        number = 10;
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    }
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;

    function subbutton() {
        squares = number;
        document.getElementById("squares").innerHTML = number;
    }
    document.getElementById("squares").innerHTML = number;
</script>

<header>

<style type>
header {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
h {
text-allign: center;
}

</style>

    <h> <br>How many squares do you want to try and pack?
    <br>
    <button type="button" onClick="button1()">1</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="button2()">2</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="button3()">3</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="button4()">4</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="button5()">5</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="button6()">6</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="button7()">7</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="button8()">8</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="button9()">9</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="button10()">10</button> --->
    <button type="button" onClick="subbutton(), draw()">Submit</button>
    <br>
    <br></h>

</header>

<script type="text/javascript">

function draw() {

h = '<style type=text/css>header {background-color: white;} h {visibility: hidden} </style>';
document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = h;

if (squares == 1) {
x = x;
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x; 
} else if (squares == 2) {
x = x + " " + x
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
} else if (squares == 3) {
    x = x + " " + x + " " + x;
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
} else if (squares == 4) {
    x = x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x;
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
} else if (squares == 5) {
    x = x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x;
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
} else if (squares == 6) {
    x = x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x;
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
} else if (squares == 7) {
    x = x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x;
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
} else if (squares == 8) {
    x = x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x;
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
} else if (squares == 9) {
    x = x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x;
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
} else if (squares == 10) {
    x = x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x + " " + x;
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
}

}
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = h;
</script>
<body>

<h id="h"></h>

<p id="squares"></p>
<style>
p {
visibility: hidden
</style>

<a id="x"></a>

</body>
```

Comment: I would probably be tempted to use one of the libraries out there, like Raphael, Snap, SVG.js that have drag and transforms like rotation already done.